# How to enable/disable JMS listener on runtime? Can I create one api which enables/disables listener on runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I am working on a Problem where I need to enable/disable a JMS listener on runtime(without restarting application). I want to create a rest service which will be hit manually and it has to turn on/turn off the listener on runtime.

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Yeah,  I managed to solve the issue, do you still want some help on this?

Comment: Yes please, I would like to know how you solved it

Comment: could you please help?

Comment: Sure, But I am not sure if I can share code here.

Comment: I just want to know the main idea

Comment: I made use DefaultMessageListenerContainer bean to give option to start, stop the listeners. You will have to create a configuration bean with queue config details,  on some action use this config bean(DefaultMessageListenerContainer) to start/stop the listeners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should provide more information about how you are using the framework. Assuming you mean `@JmsListener`, you can use the registry to stop/start the listener container...

```java
@JmsListener(id = "foo")
...

@Autowired
private JmsListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

...

    registry.getListenerContainer("foo").stop();
...
    registry.getListenerContainer("foo").start();
```

Comment: Hi @Gary Russell - I was enable to enable the listener with this however registry.getListenerContainer("foo").stop(); did not stop the listener.

Comment: It will stop it from consuming records, but the consumer will remain open. Call `shutDown()` to stop completely (and `initialize()` before starting again).

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over your processing model (synchronous/asynchronous) you could choose to use synchronously getting the messages: `MessageConusmer.receive(long timeout)`
Then you would simply stop making this call while 'logged out' and start making this call while being logged in.

If you are forced to use async. reception (with onMessage() ) then your receive will continuously receive messages  unless you stop the session with `Session.close()`. To restart you would have to re-create and restart the session and re-create your MessageConsumer